# How many Connections are needed for Phone Taps?

Tags: prison-architect

I am connecting a large amount of Phone Booths to Taps for <strike>illegal NSA wiretapping</strike> stopping Contraband. In the past, I have used two-way connections between Taps and Booths, but I like to keep my Wires organizes and that gets messy fast. I have not been able to find any information or test this myself as I have `EnableMisconduct` off.

**Do you need a two-way connection for Phone Taps to work?**

I'd also like to know if it's the same for Cctvs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need a two way connection.  Both CCTV systems and phone taps connect from the base unit to the peripheral components:  CCTV monitor --> CCTV camera and Phone Tap --> Phone Booth.

An easy way to check this in the utilities view is that wires not currently transmitting a signal are blue.  Reasons for this are

1. Incorrectly wired objects
2. CCTV cameras are cycling because more than 8 are connected to one monitor
3. Phone taps are cycling as part of their normal behaviour
4. Door control systems are not currently triggering a servo
5. Timers are switched off

Wires that are operational are coloured red/orange.

The more phones that are connected to a single phone tap the less time they will be listened to as the operative has to listen in on many conversations.

Happy spying!